# EXCEL show total count from sheets when using multiple drop down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. On each sheet you can select a user from a drop-down list and then select an item from a different drop-down list. There can be multiple instances of user and item on any sheet.

I need to have a summary sheet where you can select the user from a drop-down list and excel will display the sum total for each item the sheets.

[image: screenshot of example sheet]

I am able to collect single results using the following formula

```
=COUNTIFS('15'!$C:$C, E4, '15'!$D:$D, E5)
```

My sheets are titled 1 through to 31.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use COUNTIFS across multiple sheets that have the same column structure, combine it with SUMPRODUCT and INDIRECT.

First, list all of the Sheet Names in column A of your summary sheet that you want to include in the COUNTIFS function. For example, since your worksheets are named 1 through 31, type "*Sheet List*" in cell A1, then input values 1 through 31 in cells A2 through A32.

The COUNTIFS example you provided can now be modified to include all worksheets listed in range A2:A32 as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A2:A32&"'!C2:C1000"), E4, INDIRECT("'"&A2:A32&"'!D2:D1000"), E5))
```

NOTE: since this formula is calculating across 31 sheets, avoid using entire column references like "C:C" or "D:D"; rather, choose a reasonable amount of rows that extends far enough below your data, but not too far that it causes slow performance.  In this example, I've used "C2:C1000" and "D2:D1000".

To achieve the final summary sheet, as shown in your screenshot provided, use the correct combination of absolute and relative range references in order to be able to copy the formula across all rows and columns of the summary area. For example, with the sheet list in range A2:A32, the user list in range C2:C3 and the item list in range D1:F1, use the following formula in cell D2, then copy it across and down to complete the report:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$A$2:$A$32&"'!C2:C1000"), $C2, INDIRECT("'"&$A$2:$A$32&"'!D2:D1000"), D$1))
```

The final results should look something like this:

[image: sumproduct_countifs.jpg]